# Ошибки E0167 и E2664

Tags: c++

у меня появились ошибки в коде. Можете объяснить, пожалуйста, ясно и понятно. Я не сильно разбираюсь в C++.

```
if (!init)
    {
        BaseAddress = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(xorstr("client.dll")); //ошибки эти
        baseEngine = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(xorstr("engine.dll")); // ошибки эти
        InitImGui(pDevice);
        init = true;
    }
```

[image: ошибки]

Answer (score 1):

Работаете с широкими символами (Unicode), а передаете "узкие". Попробуйте

```
    BaseAddress = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(xorstr(L"client.dll")); //ошибки эти
    baseEngine = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(xorstr(L"engine.dll")); // ошибки эти
```

Comment: Не помогло, также остались ошибки, но уже другие. Вот они: https://imgur.com/a/QLVjony

Comment: Ну вы же не рассказываете, что такое `xorstr`, вот и приходится говорить о том, что видно. Значит, эта функция возвращает `char*` вместо `wchar_t*`. Вы не привели минимальный компилируемый пример, а без этого ситуация - как чинить автомобиль по телефону...

Answer (score 1):

Вызов функции с не подходящим аргументом. Для вызова нужна строка типа LPCWSTR, а Вы даёте char*.

[Конвертирование char* в LPCWSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858524/convert-char-to-lpwstr)

Comment: Для меня это слишком сложно :(